# Make a hole with Boolean but without 'fill cap'

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Here's a question. I'm dissecting a paprika based on a reference image. Now I'm 'slicing' the paprika with the Boolean tool, but this has an *automatic fill-cap function*. What I mean by that is that it fills the mesh instead of leaving me a hollow paprika, as I desire. Please check the attached images for more clearity.

**Is it possible to disable the fill-cap (like at the Curve Modifier)? Is there maybe a better/different non-destructive method than the Boolean Modifier?**

*Oh, and FYI I'm using this non-destructive way of modelling because I'm not sure how thick or thin I want my paprika slices to be and I'd probably want to keep tweaking it 'till the end.*

[image: Paprika dissection][image: Fresh Paprika]

Comment: Try to "solidify" it before the boolean.

Comment: pretty fly for a solidify, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the paprika hollow non-destructively by using a solidify modifier before the boolean:

[image: using solidify]

Like you mentioned, because this is a modifier, you can tweak the thickness whenever you want.